# Custom view doesn't appear for the first time swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift4

When user open my app for the first time, my custom view doesn't appear. But the next time it works fine.

I am calling this view when user taps on button.

```
let menu = MenuView(image: image, title: "text", buttons: buttons)
menu.show(animated: true)
```

Custom View code

```
class MenuView: UIView, Menu {

  var background = UIView()
  var blackOverlay = UIView()

  convenience init(image: UIImage, title: String, buttons: [UIButton]) {
    self.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    setupView(image: image, title: title, buttons: buttons)
  }

  @objc func cancelTapped() {
    hide(animated: true)
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  func setupView(image: UIImage, title: String, buttons: [UIButton]) {
    blackOverlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    blackOverlay.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
    addSubview(blackOverlay)
    let backgroundWidth = self.frame.width - CGFloat(80.0)
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: (backgroundWidth/2)-17, y: 40, width: 34, height: 34))
    imageView.image = image
    imageView.contentMode = .center
    background.addSubview(imageView)

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let stringHeight = title.stringHeight + 14
    titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: background.center.x+8, y: 100, width: backgroundWidth-16, height: stringHeight)
    titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
    titleLabel.text = title
    titleLabel.textAlignment = .center
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    background.addSubview(titleLabel)

    var newHeight: CGFloat = 0
    for i in 0...buttons.count-1 {
      buttons[i].frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: titleLabel.frame.height + 125 + CGFloat(i*50))
      buttons[i].frame.size = CGSize(width: backgroundWidth, height: 50)
      buttons[i].setTitleColor(.gingerColor, for: .normal)
      buttons[i].setTitleColor(UIColor.gingerColor.withAlphaComponent(0.5), for: .highlighted)
      buttons[i].titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
      newHeight+=buttons[i].frame.height

      let separator = UIView()
      separator.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: titleLabel.frame.height + 125 + CGFloat(i*50))
      separator.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width, height: 1)
      separator.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "dedede")
      background.addSubview(separator)

      if i == buttons.count-1 {
        buttons[i].setTitleColor(UIColor(hexString: "9E9E9E"), for: .normal)
      }

      buttons[i].addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cancelTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

      background.addSubview(buttons[i])
    }
    background.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: center.x, y: frame.height)
    background.frame.size = CGSize(width: frame.width-80, height: 90 + titleLabel.frame.height+imageView.frame.height + CGFloat(newHeight))
    background.backgroundColor = .white
    background.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    background.layer.masksToBounds = true
    addSubview(background)
  }

}
```

and my custom view protocol & extension code:

```
protocol Menu {
  func show(animated: Bool)
  func hide(animated: Bool)
  var blackOverlay: UIView { get }
  var background: UIView { get }
}

extension Menu where Self: UIView {

  func show(animated: Bool) {
    self.blackOverlay.alpha = 0
    self.background.alpha = 0
    self.blackOverlay.center = self.center
    self.background.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.frame.height+self.background.frame.height/2)
    UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self)
    if animated {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
        self.blackOverlay.alpha = 1
        self.background.alpha = 1
      })
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
        self.background.center = self.center
      }, completion: { (completed) in
        print("completed is \(completed)")
      })
    } else {
      self.blackOverlay.alpha = 1
      self.background.alpha = 1
      self.background.center = self.center
    }
  }

  func hide(animated: Bool) {
    if animated {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
        self.blackOverlay.alpha = 0
        self.background.alpha = 0
      })
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: 0), animations: {
        self.background.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.frame.height + self.background.frame.height/2)
      }, completion: { (completed) in
        self.removeFromSuperview()
      })
    } else {
      self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I have a parameter completed in completion animation block, it returns false for the first time. All subsequent times it returns false

Comment: when user opens app or the view controller ?

Comment: After onboarding user gets to the ViewController. So the view doesn't appear on this ViewController for the first time. But if I close the app and open again - it works.

Comment: Where are you adding the `MenuView` to the view hierarchy? I don't see you adding it like `addSubview(MenuView)` here. Can you post more code that shows when you are adding and removing the view?

Comment: @AllenR I am using UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self) in show() function. Isn't it enough?
Also, I tried to add this view as subview in viewDidLoad, but it doesn't help

Comment: And why does it work for the second time? The only place where I call this view is in UIButton target.

Comment: Are you on the main thread

Comment: @agibson007 yep.

Comment: Does anything else happen when you press the button?

Comment: @agibson007 no, I am just setting this view (custom init)

Comment: Are you pushing a new controller or dismissing anything while this is happening ?

Comment: @agibson007 No. Users taps on button and then the next code triggered:
let menu = MenuView(image: image, title: "text", buttons: buttons)
menu.show(animated: true)

Show function you can see in the code in my post

Comment: Have you used the view inspector?  I think it is there just under a view

Comment: @agibson007 but animation completion block returns false for the first time. And the next time its true.

Comment: @Egor might want to edit that part of the post. So it means the menu is nil or the rootcontroller is nil when you try to set it.

Comment: @agibson007 thank you! You helped me a lot! I fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake.

I tried to present my custom view controller above rootController. But, for the very first time user's rootcontroller is the first screen of onboarding. So, my custom view tried to be shown on another controller.